# SQL LEFT JOIN and SUM() slow

Tags: t-sql, sum, left-join

I'm running a query for calculating the total length of an object.
The object is made out of several smaller segments(from a different table).
Running queries with a single segment for each object works fine, but the load gets really slow for adding more segments. (3000 objects and 9000 segments).

Below is the relevant part of my query:

```
SELECT
    t1.ObjectID,
    SUM(SegmentLength) AS TotalLength

FROM Objects t1

LEFT JOIN
    Segment t2
ON
    t1.ObjectID=t2.ObjectID AND
    t1.ProjektID=t2.ProjektID AND
    t1.CraneID = t2.CraneID

WHERE
    t1.ObjectID='esttest3' AND
    (x_ > 0 OR y_ > 0) AND
    x_ IS NOT NULL AND
    y_ IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY
    t1.ObjectID
```

This takes about 1 minute for 3000 objects with 3 segments each.

I've tried adding indices:

```
FROM Objects t1 WITH (INDEX(IX_Object_All))

LEFT JOIN
    Segment t2 WITH (INDEX(IX_Segment_All))
```

But this did not improve performance.
EDIT: These indexes were non-clustered, creating clustered indices fixed the issue. (No reference to indices was needed).

If I change the LEFT JOIN into a INNER JOIN and this makes the extracted query(the one above) instantaneous(~0 sec). However inner join still takes a minute in my original query with extra fields (basically making it a left join again I suppose, since there will be values for each object)

I also tried to create a view with calculated TotalLength and making a LEFT JOIN with the view. Still no improvement.

My final idea is to create a trigger for the Segment table to update a TotalLength field in the Object table. I worry however that this will negatively impact performance when importing projects with ~9k segments, updating the value for each one...

Comment: I really suggest you use appropriate aliases for your objects. Using aliases like `t1`, `t2`, jist makes things confusing; especially if you reference an object as `t1` in one query, `t2` in another, and `t7` in another. [Bad Habits to Kick : Using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Comment: As for your question, post the query plan of your query (using [paste the plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/)), so we can understand what the DBMS is doing

Comment: @Larnu Here's the plan, sorry about the swedish in the database, it's a legacy thing... https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rkJU0mRVP

Comment: From the plan, it doesn't look like your tables have a Clustered Index, correct? Any reason why?

Comment: @Larnu I created clustered indices and now it works like a charm. Thank you! As to why, I didn't know better. :P And neither did my predecessor it seems.